# How safe is it to photograph sunset or sunrise?

Tags: equipment-damage, canon-650d, sun, sunset, eye-damage

I took the following photographs of sunset at beach. I know that photographing sun could damage the camera or even eyes, but the intensity of the sun light at the time I captured it was so weak that I could directly look at the sun and somehow knew it wont be harmful. So my question is: How can we tell if the intensity of the light is low enough so that we can directly point the camera at sun?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do recall my cameras warning against using *live view* for something like that. Normal SLR mechanics will expose the sensor briefly and let it rest between shots. **If it's not overexposed and blown out, it's being used in the expected manner and within the sensor's capability.**

The invisible IR and UV could be over-intense without your knowing. For sunset spesifically those will be low. But for snow-blindness worries the formerly ubiquitous UV filter could help.